# How to disable scrollify.js on mobile

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am creating new web and need help with JavaScript.
What I want is disable scrollify JS on mobile.
Tried almost everything, not success.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
            $(function() {
                    $.scrollify({
                        section : ".pagescroll",
                        standardScrollElements: ".modal",
                    });
              $.scrollify.disable() // this function is for disable mobile
                });
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: How do you want to detect if a mobile device is using your code?

Comment: for example detect screen size < 600px

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window) SO question

Comment: Have you tried [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead? It has multiple responsive options.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.scrollify({
    touchScroll: false
});
```

`touchScroll`: A boolean to define whether Scrollify handles touch scroll events. True by default.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check if it's mobile using `userAgent` and `regex` like this

You can execute your `script` only if it's not mobile

```
if(!(/Android|webOS|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) { //if not these devices(userAgents)

  $(function() {
      $.scrollify({
          section : ".pagescroll",
          standardScrollElements: ".modal",
      });
  });

}
```

You can try the below snippet in mobile `SO` site also. It's working

```js
if(!(/Android|webOS|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) { //if not these userAgents
  console.log("Not Mobile..!");
}else{
  console.log("This is Mobile");
}
```

Comment: Looking at the userAgent is not a very good idea; it is not reliable and must be maintained.

Comment: need a help because I am newbie in JavaScript functions.
Thank you

Comment: tried and not working. Any other solution? thank you

Comment: `if(!(/Android|webOS|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) { //if not these userAgents
     $(function() {
         $.scrollify({
             section : ".pagescroll",
             standardScrollElements: ".modal",
         });
     });
   }else{
     $.scrollify.disable();
   }`

Comment: The problem is that, when I use the
`$.scrollify.disable()`
I can not roll page up and down. It is disabling whole web.
I think this function disable the whole scroll. But I want only turn off scrollify.js.
Maybe it is need to be enabled back somehow.

Comment: Try removing `else` part of your code. i.e don't disable `scrollify` which means we're not initialising in Mobile

Answer (score 0):

check this code...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();

    if (width > 980 && height > 500) {
        $(function () {
            $(".panel").css({
                "height": $(window).height()
            });
            $.scrollify({
                section: ".panel"
            });


            $(".scroll").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.scrollify("move", $(this).attr("href"));
            });
        });

    } else {
        $(".scroll").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $.scrollify.destroy();
    }
    $(window).resize(function () {
        width = $(window).width();
        height = $(window).height();
        $(function () {
            if (width > 980 && height > 500) {
                $(".panel").css({
                    "height": $(window).height()
                });
                $.scrollify({
                    section: ".panel"
                });


                $(".scroll").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.scrollify("move", $(this).attr("href"));
                });
            } else {
                $.scrollify.destroy();
                $(".scroll").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When posting an answer, please include comments explaining what was the issue and how your code resolves it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.scrollify({
 section : ".fullSec",
 scrollSpeed:2000,
 easing: "easeOutExpo",
 offset : 0,
 scrollbars: true,
 setHeights: true,
 updateHash: false,
 afterResize: function() {
 if( $(window).width() < 767) {
   $.scrollify.disable()
 }else{
   $.scrollify.enable()
 }
 },
});
```